# what counts as a "pageview"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ads

My main index.html page consists of 2 parts (it is written in html & jquery/javascript):

1. a fixed header that is always at the top of the page
2. a content page that is loaded when a user clicks a button (ie click "blog" and the "content" div tag gets loaded w/ the blog contents. Click "about" and the "content" div tag gets loaded w/ the about us page.

When the user clicks a button on the page, the index.html and header do NOT reload; only the "content" div tag on index.html refreshes with new info.

I am using CPM advertising. This may sound like an obvious question but because the user stays on "index.html" and doesn't explicitly navigate to a "blog.html" page nor a "about.html" page, will that hurt my advertising revenue? Or, are the ad networks (buysellads.com, etc) smart enough to figure out that the user IS loading new content implicitly?

EDIT: The ad would be w/in the fixed header portion, not in the "content" part

Comment: This would be something to ask CPM advertising, or *maybe* on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Not here anyway.

Comment: i would not worry so much about the advertising company, as i would worry from google not liking this kind of thing.

Comment: @Dementic: why would google care? you're saying that google doesn't like infinite scroll?

Comment: not sure why this got closed when it got 4 upvotes. Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking CPM, CPI, CPV etc advertisement is based on the loading of an advert, exclusive of reload actions from the advert itself.

With that said since you aren't actually changing page but rather updating the contents of a div container you're not creating a new impression of the header advert therefore not incrementing your CP* count.

Comment: This is assuming that the ads are in the section which doesn't reload.

Comment: It assumes that ginius described his site accurately, prior to his edit the only advert was in the header. Now that the opening thread topic has been edited it has been explicitly stated that the advert is solely in the banner.

Comment: @SOLIVER: I think you need to re-read my question....the edit was to clarify that the ad was in the header and not in the content div. I don't mention "banner" anywhere.

Comment: @ginius Sorry I meant header, header ads are almost ubiquitously banners I didn't intend on using the terms interchangeably.

Comment: still not sure why this got closed with upvotes on my question and a decent answer